# Yocto: oe_runmake failed, error in do-install of the package libgdata

Tags: linux, yocto, arm7

I am building a `core-image-sato` for **[Cubietruck](http://www.cubietruck.com/)** in **[Yocto](https://www.yoctoproject.org/)** Poky, I've included `abiword` in the package but I get error in `do-install` of the package `libgdata_0.7.1.bb`.

#### This is the error I get

```
ERROR: oe_runmake failed - ... meta-oe/meta-gnome/recipes-gnome/libgdata/libgdata_0.7.1.bb, do_install) failed with exit code '1'
```

in the log file this is the start of the error:

```
.. 
/bin/sh: /home/user/install-sh: No such file or directory
| /usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/home/user/build        
/tmp/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/libgdata/0.7.1-r0/image     /usr/share/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES/gdata.mo': No such file or directory
```

... and it continues.

I have no idea what causes the error, I've tried different image types and `bitbake -c clean libgdata` and started the process over and over but I'll get the same error.